# Incorrect implementation of QuickSort

Tags: java, debugging, sorting, quicksort

I am learning about [Quick Sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hHWpuAPBHo) from Youtube and am trying to implement the implementation as viewed where the pivot will be swapped with 1 element before the left marker

This is the pseudocode of the QuickSort algorithm

```
Method
Divide-and-conquer
Pick an element (pivot) from the list
Pivot is arbitrarily chosen
Normally, the first element is selected
Partition the list into two halves such that:
All the elements in the first half is smaller than the pivot
All the elements in the second half is greater than the pivot
After the rearrangement, the pivot element (pivot) occupies a proper position in a sorting of the list.
Recursively
Quick-sort the 1st half
Quick-sort the 2nd half
```

## Java Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;



public class QuickSort 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Vector<Integer> container = new Vector<Integer>();

        String userinput = "data1.txt";
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner("foo"); // variable used to read file

        try
        {
            //open filename

            File inputfile = new File("C:\\Users\\8382c\\workspace\\AdvanceAlgorithmA3_Quicksort\\src\\" + userinput);
             myScanner = new Scanner(inputfile);

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File cant be found");
        }


         String line = myScanner.nextLine(); //read 1st line which contains the number of numbers to be sorted

         while(myScanner.hasNext())
         {
             container.add(myScanner.nextInt());
         }


        System.out.println(line);

        /*container.add(7);
        container.add(2);
        container.add(3);
        container.add(4);
        container.add(8);
        container.add(6);
        container.add(8);
        container.add(9);*/

        quickSort(container,0,7);

        for (int i =0;i<container.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(container.get(i));
        }

        //http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort




    }


    public static int partition(Vector<Integer> container, int left, int right)
    {
          int i = left, j = right;
          int tmp;


          int pivot = container.get(left);

          i++;

          while (i <= j) 
          {
                while ( container.get(i) < pivot)
                      i++;
                while ( container.get(j) > pivot)
                      j--;
                if (i <= j) 
                {
                      tmp =  container.get(i);

                      container.set(i, container.get(j));
                      container.set(j, tmp);

                      i++;
                      j--;
                }
          };

          tmp = container.get(left);

          container.set(left, container.get(i-1));
          container.set(i-1, tmp);

          return i-1;
    }

    public static void quickSort(Vector<Integer> container, int left, int right) 
    {
          int index = partition(container, left, right);
          if (left < index - 1)
                quickSort(container, left, index - 1);
          if (index+1 < right)
                quickSort(container, index+1, right);
    }


}
```

The algorithm works for the following numbers : {7,23,4,8,6,8,9}

However it does not work when i try to sort a [text file](http://pastebin.com/9h5QpD92) which contains 10000 numbers

**What am i doing wrongly in the algorithm ???**

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @rob its ok , i got it already , thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

For starters, this statement:

```
quickSort(container,0,7);
```

Should read:

```
quickSort(container,0,container.size()-1);
```

I'm not sure if that was the problem or not.  Now let's clean up your code.

Your core function:

```
public static void quickSort(Vector<Integer> container, int left, int right) 
{
      int index = partition(container, left, right);
      if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(container, left, index - 1);
      if (index+1 < right)
            quickSort(container, index+1, right);
}
```

Appears to have an off by one error with regards to plus/minus 1 with the index.  This looks more appropriate:

```
public static void quickSort(Vector<Integer> container, int left, int right) 
{
      if (left < right)
      {
          int index = partition(container, left, right);
          quickSort(container, left, index);
          quickSort(container, index+1, right);
      }
}
```

And your partition function needs some cleanup as well.  I had messed this up the first time I posted it.  Now that I tested it, I know it to work.

```
public static int partition(Vector<Integer> container, int left, int right)
{
      int i = left-1;
      int j = right+1;

      int pivot = container.get(left);

      while (true) 
      {
          do
          {
              i++;
          } while (container.get(i) < pivot);

          do
          {
              j--;
          } while (container.get(j) > pivot);

          if (i < j) 
          {
                int tmp =  container.get(i);
                container.set(i, container.get(j));
                container.set(j, tmp);
          }
          else
          {
              break;
          }
      };
      return j;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am wondering if this method swaps the pivot and one element before the left marker??

Comment: The "one before the left marker" can't happen because the initial assignment of `i = left - 1` is complemented with the first statement int the while loop calling `i++`. A swap can never happen if j is less than i.  btw, this code is simply transposed from the format Quicksort/Partition definition from [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Electrical-Engineering-Computer/dp/0262031418/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1407478588&sr=8-3&keywords=algorithms+rivest).

Answer (score 0):

Selbie answer does work as expected however it was not the implementation I was looking. I was looking for the version of Quick Sort where the pivot swaps with one before the left marker resulting in one element being in place after every iteration.

After much trial & error , I realised my original algorithm works , I have no idea why it did not worked initially when i first posted the algorithm in the question

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;



public class QuickSort 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Vector<Integer> container = new Vector<Integer>();


        container.add(7);
        container.add(2);
        container.add(3);
        container.add(4); // 7 2 3 4 8 6 8 9
        container.add(8); // 7 2 3 4 6 8 8 9        
        container.add(6); // 6 2 3 4 7 8 8 9
        container.add(8);
        container.add(9);

        quickSort(container,0,container.size()-1);

        for (int i =0;i<container.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(container.get(i));
        }



    }


    public static int partition(Vector<Integer> container, int left, int right)
    {
          int i = left, j = right;
          int tmp;


          int pivot = container.get(left);

          i++;

          while (i <= j) 
          {
                while ( container.get(i) < pivot)
                      i++;
                while ( container.get(j) > pivot)
                      j--;
                if (i <= j) 
                {
                      tmp =  container.get(i);

                      container.set(i, container.get(j));
                      container.set(j, tmp);

                      i++;
                      j--;
                }
          };

          tmp = container.get(left);

          container.set(left, container.get(i-1));
          container.set(i-1, tmp);

          return i-1;





    }

    public static void quickSort(Vector<Integer> container, int left, int right) 
    {
          int index = partition(container, left, right);
          if (left < index - 1)
                quickSort(container, left, index - 1);
          if (index+1 < right)
                quickSort(container, index+1, right);



    }


}
```